# Start MC in terminal mode

Tags: command-line, configuration, mc

Is there a command line switch or configuration option so that MC starts in terminal mode (same as if I would press ctrl-o after running mc).

Answer (score 0):

The [mc(1) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mc) mentions no such option.

Looking around in the [source](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/4a0f265d95643b4f0f84c388b12acf1f406b63a6/src/keybind-defaults.c#L124) shows that this action can be bound to a different key sequence, using `Shell  = ...` in the keymap file, but that doesn't help invoke it at startup.  It may also be invokable through a callback using the `MSG_ACTION` event, but I couldn't see a way to reach that from outside the process.

One possibility is to have the Ctrl-o sequence sent automatically when you start `mc`.  If you are running `mc` in a terminal emulator on X11, you could do this using an X automation tool such as [xdotool](http://man.cx/xdotool).  Put

```
xdotool key ctrl+o
```

in your `~/.local/share/mc/bashrc` (or equivalent if you are using a different shell).

If you want to enable this only some of the time, set up an alternative config directory and point to it with the environment variable `MC_HOME`.  You would need to put that same `xdotool` line in `~/alt_mc/.local/share/mc/bashrc`, and start `mc` with

```
MC_HOME=$HOME/alt_mc mc
```

This will require duplicating/symlinking any other `mc` config settings and files that you have in the usual place.

Comment: Thanks for xdotool but I wanted this behavior only when requested i.e. I want to assign something like "gnome-terminal -e 'mc --run-shell; exit'" to keyboard shortcut. In other cases I want mc to behave normally.

Comment: You could do that with an alternative `mc` config dir.  Edited to demonstrate.